# EF (6.1) Code-First stored procedure issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first

So I have a reverse engineered (code first) approach to EF 6.1. I'm using the POCO generator VS Extension to generate (reverse engineer) my tables from the existing database, etc.

In my context class, I have calls to stored procedures wired up for Insert, Delete and Update events, this is the one in question:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<StandardAdditionalInformation>().MapToStoredProcedures(s => 
            s.Insert(u => u.HasName("standard_additionalinformation_save")
                    .Parameter(p => p.Notes, "Notes")
                    .Parameter(p => p.StandardOptout, "StandardOptout")
                    .Parameter(p => p.StandardOptoutReason, "StandardOptoutReason")
                    .Parameter(p => p.IsDeleted, "IsDeleted")
                    .Parameter(p => p.CreateDate, "CreateDate")
                    .Parameter(p => p.CreatedByAccountId, "CreatedByAccountId")
                    .Parameter(p => p.UpdateDate, "UpdateDate")
                    .Parameter(p => p.ModifiedByAccountId, "ModifiedByAccountId")
            ).Update(u => u.HasName("standard_additionalinformation_save")
                    .Parameter(p => p.StandardId, "StandardId")
                    .Parameter(p => p.ClassId, "ClassId")
                    .Parameter(p => p.Notes, "Notes")
                    .Parameter(p => p.StandardOptout, "StandardOptout")
                    .Parameter(p => p.StandardOptoutReason, "StandardOptoutReason")
                    .Parameter(p => p.IsDeleted, "IsDeleted")
                    .Parameter(p => p.CreateDate, "CreateDate")
                    .Parameter(p => p.CreatedByAccountId, "CreatedByAccountId")
                    .Parameter(p => p.UpdateDate, "UpdateDate")
                    .Parameter(p => p.ModifiedByAccountId, "ModifiedByAccountId")
            ).Delete(u => u.HasName("standard_additionalinformation_delete")
                    .Parameter(p => p.StandardId, "StandardId")
                    .Parameter(p => p.ClassId, "ClassId")
        ));
```

So, basically, calling the stored proc is as simple as
    db.Set().Add(value);
    //where value is a StandardAdditionalInformation object.
    db.SaveChanges();

For the vast majority of the calls (99%) it will be an update.

My issue is here: When I call the update, I'm presented with an Exception:

```
Procedure or function standard_additionalinformation_save has too many arguments specified.
```

So, after digging further, running a SQL trace, etc, I came up with this being the ACTUAL update call:

```
exec [dbo].[gsp_dal_teacherclass_standard_additionalinformation_save] @StandardId=12,@ClassId=1,@Notes=N'blah',@StandardOptout=0,@StandardOptoutReason=N'',@IsDeleted=0,@CreateDate='2014-05-02 13:03:00',@CreatedByAccountId=34068,@UpdateDate='2014-05-12 10:05:04.6067328',@ModifiedByAccountId=34068,@StandardAdditionalInformation_StandardId=NULL,@StandardAdditionalInformation_ClassId=NULL
```

EF Seems to be injecting 2 parameters into the Sproc call:

```
@StandardAdditionalInformation_StandardId=NULL
@StandardAdditionalInformation_ClassId=NULL
```

These are NOT referenced in the code ANYWHERE, but they are, however, the values for the PK on the table itself.

Is there something I'm missing? I mean, should the stored proc not be called with just the params that are defined in the context builder?
My work around has been to add these two parameters to the sproc and that works just fine, I just think it's a pretty dirty solution and don't want it getting to prod!

Answer (score 0):

After digging further into it, I found the table in question had a PK and FK that were identical.
I removed the FK and modified the PK to be more in line with some change that were made to the table structure AFTER this code was written and boom, it works.

I guess I pose this question for the "solution":

Does EF generate code that would force parameters for the stored procedure? Ie. Does EF recognize the existance of the PK/FK and know to look for a many-to-many relationship, so it injects parameters that it believes should be there?